# EEA national under article 10 can apply permanent residence card

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I would like to ask about EEA national. I am Italian but my father has a Indian passport and he depends on me . My father has a residence card of a family member of a union citizen. Now he came hear with me without visa under article 10. I would like to ask you what I can do next? Can I apply directly for permanent residence card or I need a apply for EEA family permit.thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have an EEA family permit before applying for a residence card.  See [Apply for a UK residence card/Documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/documents-you-must-provide):

> For each person on the application you’ll need to provide:
>
> - a current passport
> - 2 passport size colour photographs
> - one passport size colour photograph of your European Economic Area (EEA) national (or British citizen) sponsor
> - your EEA family member’s valid passport or national identity card
> - evidence of your relationship to your EEA family member - such as a marriage certificate, civil partnership certificate, birth certificate, or proof that you’ve lived together for 2 years if you’re unmarried
>
> You also need to provide proof of one of the following, depending on your eligibility:
>
> - that your EEA family member has a permanent right of residence
> - that your EEA family member is a ‘qualified person’
> - that you qualify because of a ‘retained right of residence’
> - that you qualify for a ‘Surinder Singh’ application

Nowhere is the EEA family permit mentioned.